# How can I make an Android app auto update without user knowing?

Tags: android, apk, updates, auto-update, user-permissions

I'm building an Android application and significant updates would be rolled out every month, this is because the app development would be using a lot of feedback from users for development. I want to make this app auto update without asking the user to do so.
Is this possible?

Comment: Are you building your own hardware with your own Android-based firmware?

Comment: You cannot update the app without any user interaction.